# Debian Stretch apt-get update failure resolving 'ftp.de.debian.org'

Tags: debian, apt

Since I have updated debian from jessie to stretch *apt-get update* fails.

Error Message:

```
Err:1 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ftp.de.debian.org'
```

Internet and DNS are working fine.

This workaround can fix the problem:
[Stretch apt update failing, missing InRelease file on mirrors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478309/stretch-apt-update-failing-missing-inrelease-file-on-mirrors)

But my question is: 
**Is it possible to fix apt that I can use it again as usual?**

ouptput: dig ftp.de.debian.org :

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> ftp.de.debian.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20953
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ftp.de.debian.org.             IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ftp.de.debian.org.      365     IN      A       141.76.2.4

;; Query time: 31 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 26 10:30:37 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 62
```

output ls -l /etc/resolv.conf : `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 62 Feb 19 13:07 /etc/resolv.conf`

output cat /etc/resolv.conf `nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4 nameserver 192.168.1.2`

**EDIT:**
cat /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:  dns files
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: I've had `dig` circumvent my own machine's DNS settings / DNS cache so I don't usually trust it for diagnosing this type of issue.  Could you try a simpler test: `ping ftp.de.debian.org`.  If this immediately resolves an IP then it categorically proves your DNS settings are working.

Comment: ping ftp.de.debian.org fails with `the name or the service is unknown` so after allt it seems to be a DNS Problem

Comment: Is it possible you have firewall rules in place that do not allow you to talk with the outside?

Comment: The (longish) output of `strace getent hosts ftp.de.debian.org` might give us a clue. If you haven't got `strace` installed, adding the `141.76.2.4 ftp.de.debian.org` line to `/etc/hosts` might help, but don't forget to remove it immediately after the install.