# apt-get update failed to fetch debian amd64 packages while building dockerfile from maven:3.5.2-jdk-8

Tags: debian, apt, docker, maven

Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip
RUN pip install awscli --upgrade
```

Build Logs:

```
Preparing build context archive…
[==================================================>]3380/3380 files
Done

Sending build context to Docker daemon…
[==================================================>] 23.19MB
Done

Step 1/17 : FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8
 ---> d07bef19f01a
Step 2/17 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip
 ---> Running in ebed1b8ce61e
Ign:1 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates Release
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Err:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Err:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Err:11 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:12 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main all Packages
Reading package lists...
W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error response from daemon: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip' returned a non-zero code: 100
Failed to deploy '<unknown> Dockerfile: Dockerfile': Can't retrieve image ID from build stream
```

This Dockerfile used to build fine and has only recently started throwing this error

Comment: Definitely use a newer base image, i.e., release upgrade your system.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[Stretch has been moved to archive.debian.org](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2023/03/msg00006.html), you need to update your repository configuration or better yet, **use a newer base image**.

To update your repository configuration, change `deb.debian.org` to `archive.debian.org` in lines referencing Stretch in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: Any link to newer base images that could be used?

Comment: @AniMenon [take your pick](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven), I can’t choose for you ;-).

Comment: Ok :D  
I was actually looking for a debian with java8 image, not maven specifically..

Comment: Well, the question is about a Maven image ;-). For Debian with Java 8, use `debian:unstable` and install `openjdk-8-jre-headless` or whichever package is most appropriate; or use whatever base release of Debian you want, and add Thorsten Glaser’s backport repository (see [#989736](https://bugs.debian.org/989736) for details).

Comment: will check that out, thanks.

Answer (score 63):

Thanks @stephen-kitt! I would expect them to update the docker images with this change :(

If it helps anyone we needed to update our docker image (`python:3.7.3-slim`) with the following change to bypass the error (while still being able to install basic packages):

`RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list`

at least the PGP key was left untouched...

Comment: You’re using a 4-year-old image — once a version-specific image is tagged, it’s common practice not to update it. What you should really do is switch to a newer image, *e.g.* 3.7.16-bullseye if you want a version-specific image, 3.7-bullseye if you want to always track the latest 3.7 image using Bullseye.

Comment: I need more lines in my sources.list in order to apt install packages like curl:`RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`
`RUN echo "deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`
`RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`
`RUN echo  "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`
`RUN echo  "deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Better yet, use https:


`RUN echo "deb https://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 9):

Thank you @Stephen_Kitt and @Ben_Kaplan for the helpful answers!

Inspired by them, i added the following to my Dockerfile to switch to archive.debian.org:

```
RUN sed -i s/deb.debian.org/archive.debian.org/g /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN sed -i s/security.debian.org/archive.debian.org/g /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN sed -i s/stretch-updates/stretch/g /etc/apt/sources.list
```

With that, all works fine and no misleading error messages pops up.

Edit: By the comment below by *Scott G*, this works only if there are no other sources listet thant `deb.debian.org`.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. You want to replace the entire sources.list file like @ben-kaplan does in his answer. Otherwise, if your sources.list file has other entries it can still cause `apt update` to fail. This is because if you have a `security.debian.org` entry for the `stretch/updates` distribution, this should be removed. Or if you have a `deb.debian.org` entry with `stretch-updates`, this will be replaced with the `sed` command to incorrectly point to `archive.debian.org` for the `stretch-updates` distribution which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Scott G: Thank you for that hint and you are completely right. The `sources.list` in our docker-image don't have any entries to `security.debian.org`, so i didn't think that this can also be a option for others.

Answer (score 3):

For a node 12 image with similar issues I also had to add the debian security to be able to install libnotify

By adding the below lines I managed to get the docker image working again.

The first line overwrites any existing content in sources.list, the rest append tot the "new" sources file.

```
RUN MAJOR_VERSION=$(echo $NODE_VERSION | cut -d '.' -f 1) && \
    if [ "$MAJOR_VERSION" = "12" ] ; then \
    echo "deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo 'deb-src [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib'  >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo 'deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main non-free contrib'  >> /etc/apt/sources.list; \
    fi
```

Comment: This should be the top answer, IMO. It doesn't give a partial answer and then 'instruct' the obvious about an old node:12 image: it just answers the question with a complete solution