# Error 404 appears when running apt-get update. Debian

Tags: debian, apt, docker, deb, docker-compose

When I run the docker-compose build command, the Dockerfile does not build and I get the following error:

```
[app  2/21] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libzip-dev libonig-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libmagickwand-dev libicu-dev libgmp-dev re2c libmhash-dev libmcrypt-dev curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev cron supervisor file msmtp wget ssh git mariadb-client iputils-ping net-tools dnsutils libmemcached-dev libzmq3-dev logrotate --no-install-recommends:

0.978 Ign:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
1.056 Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
1.282 Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
...

5.750 Err:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
5.750   404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.66.132 80]
...
12.85 Err:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
12.85   404  Not Found
...
```

How can I solve this problem and build the Dockerfile successfully? What could be causing the 404 error when installing packages via apt-get?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        libgmp-dev \
        re2c \
        libmhash-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        curl \
        libcurl3 \
        libcurl3-dev \
        cron \
        supervisor \
        file \
        msmtp \
        wget \
        ssh \
        git \
        mariadb-client \
        iputils-ping \
        net-tools \
        dnsutils \
        libmemcached-dev \
        libzmq3-dev \
        logrotate \
            --no-install-recommends

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql curl

RUN pecl install memcached-2.2.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached

RUN pecl install memcache-2.2.7 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcache

RUN pecl install xdebug-2.5.5 \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick

#  --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip intl mbstring pdo_mysql exif \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN pecl install zmq-beta \
    && docker-php-ext-enable zmq

#RUN ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h /usr/local/include/ \
#    && docker-php-ext-configure gmp \
#    && docker-php-ext-install gmp

#RUN BEFORE_PWD=$(pwd) \
#    && mkdir -p /opt/xdebug \
#    && cd /opt/xdebug \
#    && curl -k -L https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/archive/XDEBUG_2_5_5.tar.gz | tar zx \
#    && cd xdebug-XDEBUG_2_5_5 \
#    && phpize \
#    && ./configure --enable-xdebug \
#    && make clean \
#    && sed -i 's/-O2/-O0/g' Makefile \
#    && make \
#    # && make test \
#    && make install \
#    && cd "${BEFORE_PWD}" \
#    && rm -r /opt/xdebug


COPY ./install-composer.sh /
COPY ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY ./crontab /etc/cron.d/cron
COPY ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY ./www.conf /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY ./msmtprc /etc/
COPY ./app_logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/app

RUN chmod 0644 /etc/logrotate.d/app

RUN apt-get purge -y g++ \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* \
    && sh /install-composer.sh \
    && rm /install-composer.sh

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cron

VOLUME /root/.composer
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 9000

# CMD ["php-fpm"]

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

Full Docker-compose error:

```
[+] Running 52/18
 ✔ nginx 7 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                                                                                                                        575.3s
 - db 11 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣤⣿⣿] 37.02MB/64.27MB Pulling                                                                                                                                                     588.9s
[+] Running 52/18 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled
 ✔ nginx 7 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                                                                                                                        575.3s
 - db 11 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣤⣿⣿] 37.02MB/64.27MB Pulling                                                                                                                                                     589.8s
[+] Running 52/18 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled
 ✔ nginx 7 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                                                                                                                        575.3s
 - db 11 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣤⣿⣿] 38.09MB/64.27MB Pulling                                                                                                                                                     591.9s
[+] Running 52/18 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled
 ✔ nginx 7 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                                                                                                                        575.3s
 - db 11 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣤⣿⣿] 38.09MB/64.27MB Pulling                                                                                                                                                     592.9s
[+] Running 52/18 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled
 ✔ nginx 7 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                                                                                                                        575.3s
 - db 11 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣤⣿⣿] 38.09MB/64.27MB Pulling                                                                                                                                                     593.9s
[+] Running 54/18 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled
 ✔ nginx 7 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                               575.3s
 ✔ db 11 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                             665.8s
 ✔ nginx-proxy 13 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                  278.2s
 ✔ memcached 5 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                             242.8s
 ✔ tg_web 13 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                        11.8s
[+] Building 24.0s (7/26)                                                                                docker:default
 => [app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.97kB                                                                             0.0s
 => [app internal] load .dockerignore                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [app internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:5.6-fpm                                                10.1s
 => [app auth] library/php:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                     0.0s
 => [app internal] load build context                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 217B                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [app  1/21] FROM docker.io/library/php:5.6-fpm@sha256:4f070f1b7b93cc5ab364839b79a5b26f38d5f89461f7bc0c  0.0s
 => ERROR [app  2/21] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y         zlib1g-dev         libzip-dev         lib  13.8s
------
 > [app  2/21] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y         zlib1g-dev         libzip-dev         libonig-dev         libfreetype6-dev         libjpeg62-turbo-dev         libmagickwand-dev         libicu-dev         libgmp-dev      re2c            libmhash-dev            libmcrypt-dev           curl            libcurl3        libcurl3-dev            cron            supervisor      file         msmtp         wget         ssh         git         mariadb-client         iputils-ping         net-tools         dnsutils         libmemcached-dev         libzmq3-dev         logrotate             --no-install-recommends:
0.978 Ign:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
1.056 Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
1.282 Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
1.368 Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
1.607 Ign:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
1.690 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
1.935 Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
2.093 Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
2.326 Ign:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
2.466 Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
2.645 Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
2.813 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
2.978 Ign:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
3.132 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
3.288 Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
3.452 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
3.617 Ign:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
3.968 Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
4.022 Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
4.300 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
4.333 Ign:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
4.617 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
5.451 Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
5.750 Err:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
5.750   404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.66.132 80]
6.053 Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
6.658 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
6.953 Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
7.247 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
7.625 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
7.949 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
8.245 Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
9.334 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
9.692 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
10.09 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
10.41 Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
10.79 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
11.22 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
11.55 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
12.85 Err:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
12.85   404  Not Found
13.14 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
13.45 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
13.78 Err:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
13.78   404  Not Found
13.80 Reading package lists...
13.81 W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
13.81 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
13.81 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
13.81 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.66.132 80]
13.81 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
13.81 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
13.81 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y         zlib1g-dev         libzip-dev
libonig-dev         libfreetype6-dev         libjpeg62-turbo-dev         libmagickwand-dev         libicu-dev         libgmp-dev \t    re2c \t    libmhash-dev \t    libmcrypt-dev \t    curl \t    libcurl3 \t    libcurl3-dev \t    cron \t    supervisor \t    file         msmtp         wget         ssh         git         mariadb-client         iputils-ping         net-tools         dnsutils         libmemcached-dev         libzmq3-dev         logrotate             --no-install-recommends" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Answer "[apt-get update failed to fetch debian amd64 packages while building dockerfile from maven:3.5.2-jdk-8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/743839/apt-get-update-failed-to-fetch-debian-amd64-packages-while-building-dockerfile-f)" didn't solve my problem.

Based on the answers, I added this to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo  "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo  "deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN sed -i s/deb.debian.org/archive.debian.org/g /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Please, help
[image]

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/743839/apt-get-update-failed-to-fetch-debian-amd64-packages-while-building-dockerfile-f

It solved my problem